# How to pass variable using javascript/jquery from one PHP file to another PHP file

Tags: php, javascript

I have two PHP files a.php and b.php. I have some links in a.php like this:

```
echo "<ul>";    
 foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
 echo "<li><a href='NEED SOME CODE HERE TO OPEN b.php' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->link . "</a></li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

When the user clicks on that link, the second page b.php should open and ALSO b.php should know the contents of the variable `$entry->link` so that based on the`$entry->link` I can do some conditional checks like this:

in b.php, I want to do this check:

```
if($entry->link=="http://www.google.com") {
 //Some code here
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there anything you have already tried?

Comment: I have not started it yet. I am thinking about the logic how can I do this. Need this solution for one of my project that I am going to start soon. I have not written any code for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

You could just link to

```
echo "<li><a href='b.php?link=".urlencode(entry->link)."' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->link . "</a></li>";
```

And in b.php

```
if(isset($_GET['link']) && ($_GET['link']=="http://www.google.com")) {
    //Some code here
}
```

Comment: This looks great, appreciate for your reply. Can the same logic be applied if I do not use <form> and without using $_GET['link'] in the b.php file. I mean just using <a> tag in a.php and using javascript:window.open() and open the second page b.php and used that variable in b.php. In short, without using <form>?

Comment: You don't have to use form to use this code, but the get is needed. Maybe if you keep $entry in session variable, you cout retrive the right link in b.php, but if session var change before you click (by opening a second page) maybe the data in b/php will be different

Answer (score 0):

What about a.php saving the data to a session then when b.php is called that data is already available?

alt method: Querystring or POST vars to from $entry->title?

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution but here I am not using any <form> tag. I am just using the <a> tag and once user clicks on it, the file b.php will open, may be using javascript:window.open() or something like this.

Comment: That would be a way of doing it. jQuery has some very nice logic to handle passing form data page to page.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to do, here are two methods you could use:

1)Make the data persistent by using PHP session on the server side;

or

2)Saves the data locally using Web storage:

> Here's an example using DOM Storage:
>   //Stores the data
>       window.sessionStorage.setItem("key", "my data");
>   //Retrieve it
>       window.sessionStorage.getItem("key");